# Is it possible to change the name of "x" for x data?

Tags: highcharts

I receive data which I would like to chart. Unfortunately, it consist of records like

```
{
    abcisse: 5,
    ordonnee: 9
}
```

which I would like to feed into [`data`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series%3Cbubble%3E.data).

The record above corresponds, in highcharts nomenclature, to

```
{
    x: 5,
    y: 9
}
```

Is it possible to inform highcharts that he should be looking for values of `x` in `abcisse` and for values of `y` in `ordonnee`? Or do I have to postprocess the data and create `x` and `y` entries?

Comment: There's no such option. There is [keys](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.keys) option but works in a bit different way (changes `[]` arrays into `{x/y}` objects).

Comment: @PawełFus: thanks. In that case Bobby's solution below is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array map function to convert your records to the format need my highcharts. For example, if your data is in an array called myData then you could feed your data to the series.data option using...

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    ....
    series: [{
        data: myData.map(function (item) {return { x: item.abcisse, y: item.ordonnee}; })
    }]
    ...
});
```

Comment: While it does not exactly answers my question (whether it is possible to modify the variable name for the coordinates), I learned about `map()` - which is great. It almost brings in comprehensions from Python :). Thanks.